# Call Methode from a SCNNode gathered from a Collision

Tags: ios, collision, arkit, scnnode

I want to create a shooting game for ARKit on IOS. In this game I am shooting projectiles into the scene and when they collide I want to do some damage to the object that has been hit.

```
func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
        if contact.nodeA.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == PhysicType.Target.rawValue {
            //Hit target
        }else if contact.nodeB.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == PhysicType.Target.rawValue {
            //Hit target
        }
    }
```

What I am searching should look something like this:

```
let target = contact.nodeA as? Target
target.hit()
```

But it seems not to be possible, to cast the node to my Target class. The other idea was, to compare the position of the target node with all nodes in the scene. And if they have the same position, I know which node I can call the method on:

```
func hitTarget(node: SCNNode){
        for child in scene.childNodes{
            if child.name == "Target" {
                guard let target = child as? Target else  {continue}
                if target.presentation.position.x == node.presentation.position.x &&
                    target.presentation.position.y == node.presentation.position.y &&
                    target.presentation.position.z == node.presentation.position.z{
                    target.hit(damage: 5)
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I currently have one object in scene, so it has to be the target object. But somehow both positions are way different. I don't really know the difference between node.position and node.presentation.position. But I tried both.

Important to say, because I think that could be the problem: I have a center object. And all target object I add relative to that center object. So I have the rootNode->centerObj->[all target objects]
Maybe that is why the positions are not the same.

What I want to know is, how is the proper way to get the correct node, which I have hit and can cast it to the class, which it belongs to?

Comment: You have a nice idea. The question is what object will your projectile hit? The object in the real environment? or the object in the virtual scene?

Comment: in the virtual scene